# Cucumber StepDef ResultActions NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, mockmvc

I am receiving the following NullPointerException when trying to execute a Cucumber StepDefs file that passes a JSON from a `.feature` file to a REST endpoint on localhost;

- I have tried to instantiate the `ResultActions` in every other way, receiving the same error.
- The Controller works linked to the test is fine, and is pointing to the correct REST endpoint.
- The issue is with the `result` in `personStepDefs`
- I don't think I'm missing a parameter for `ResultActions result` as I've built my `RequestBuilder`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.///.v2.PersonStepDefs.i\_add\_a\_new\_Person\_using\_POST\_at\_with\_JSON([PersonStepDefs.java:49](https://PersonStepDefs.java:49)) at

✽.I add a new Person using POST at "[http://localhost:8080/services/person/add](http://localhost:8080/services/person/add)" with JSON:(file:///C:/path/to/src/test/resources/Person.feature:6)
```

**`PersonStepDefs.java`**

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
/**
 * Person Step Definition class to execute Scenario contained in Person.feature
 * @author Lewis Jones
 *
 */
public class PersonStepDefs {

    @Autowired
    private volatile WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private volatile MockMvc mockMvc;

    private ResultActions result;

    /**
     * Runs the application server before every scenario.
     */
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @When("I add a new Person using POST at {string} with JSON:")
    public void i_add_a_new_Person_using_POST_at_with_JSON(String request, String json) throws Exception {
        result = mockMvc.perform(post(request).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(json.getBytes()));
    }

    @Then("the response code should be {int}")
    public void the_response_code_should_be(Integer responseCode) throws Exception {
        result.andExpect(status().is(responseCode));
    }

}
```

**`RunMvcTest.java`**

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty","html:build/cucumber-html-report"},
        features = "src/test/resources", strict = true)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = V2Application.class)
/**
 * A class to run the Cucumber .feature files located in 'features'
 * @author Lewis Jones
 *
 */
public class RunMvcTest {

}
```

**`Person.feature`**

```
Feature: Person CRUD
  As a User, I want to add a Person

  @repo
  Scenario: Person.Repo.Add
    When I add a new Person using POST at "http://localhost:8080/services/person/add" with JSON:
      """
      {"firstName":"Lewis","lastName":"Jones","addressId":"1", "dob":"1999-07-11"}
      """
    Then the response code should be 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A null pointer exception happens when you try to de-reference a variable or field that is null. So if you try to call `perform` on `mockMvc` while `mockMvc` is null you will get a null pointer exception.

If you read the stack trace carefully you can see that this it what it tries to tell you.

```
result = mockMvc.perform(....);
```

So how can `mockMcv` be null? You initialize it in `setup` method right? That means `setup` isn't called. You can confirm this by putting a break point in the method and debugging your test.

```
import org.junit.BeforeClass;

....

    /**
     * Runs the application server before every scenario.
     */
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }
```

And `setup` doesn't get called because `BeforeClass` is a JUnit annotation. Cucumber uses `io.cucumber.java.Before`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I also realised that I missed the @Given step, using that in conjunction with your answer has made the feature file run successfully.